# java maven Weld instanciation fails

Tags: java, maven, weld

im trying to use weld for Dependency Injection in my multi module Maven Project.

i have this dependency set in my parent .pom

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
<artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

i have a beanx.xml in every module in the meta-inf folder

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd" >
</beans>
```

in my static void main i try to create my first bean from which i will run my application

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Startpoint");
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
        DecisionMaker decisionMaker = container.instance().select(DecisionMaker.class).get();
        decisionMaker.run();
        weld.shutdown();
    }
```

when trying to run the application i get this message that tells me that my weld is not running correctly

```
48 [main] INFO org.jboss.weld.Version - WELD-000900 1.1.2 (Final)
235 [main] INFO org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap - WELD-000101 Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
```

and once i try accessing an injected bean from my Decisionmaker, which works totally fine, i get an nullpointer like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.DecisionMaker.DecisionMaker.<init>(DecisionMaker.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldConstructorImpl.newInstance(WeldConstructorImpl.java:239)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.createInstance(ManagedBean.java:385)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.produce(ManagedBean.java:234)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:338)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:122)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:693)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:731)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:115)
    at TRX.TRX_Bot.App.main(App.java:19)
```

i think it has something to do with weld, but im not shure and i didnt found anything usefull. What i actually want is just an application that uses injection .

EDIT:
After deleting the Constructor of the 'DecisionMaker' class i dont have this error anymore. Im not shure what that is the case but it seems like if you want to instantiate a bean in the way i do in the static void main function the bean must not have a Constructor

Comment: i got the same exact problem. i wasted probably 6 hours on this today. CDI in java is so confusing, everyone contradicts each other on google. i cant seem to be able to find ONE complete, full explanation and a working example. all the "java SE" tutorials on CDI dont work.

Comment: i actually have it working now, my problem was that i had a constructor in my 'decisionMaker' class. Once i delete the constructor the application started how i wanted it to be.